# Does WebGL auto convert to DirectX in Windows Universal App?

Tags: webgl, winjs, win-universal-app

as I know that chrome and firefox they will convert WebGL to be DirectX when user using windows platform, so how about in Windows Universal App ?

If I using WebGL in Javascript Windows Universal Project, Does it covert to DirectX via ANGLE ?

Comment: According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2013/11/19/using-webgl-to-create-games-for-the-windows-store.aspx) found by searching for `winjs webgl`, yes as everything webgl is run through directx on windows.

Comment: thanks, I read that before too, just want to confirm it again :)